# How to use django default group permission in django-graphene?

Tags: django, permissions, graphql, graphene-python

I want to do a API with django-graphene, but i want to apply the django default group permission when i user make a request this will have permission if his user-group allow him to CRUD.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an elegant solution, but it's one that works for mutations:

In my mutation, I have a custom function that returns true if the user pulled from info.context.user is in a group, or false if they are not:

```
class RelayCreateConversation(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    # Set a variable as the field we want to use
    conversation = graphene.Field(ConversationNode)
    # Create a custom response as a string if the user doesn't have authentication
    custom_response = graphene.String()

    # What is passed through in the mutation
    class Input:
        participant_number = graphene.String()

    def mutate_and_get_payload(root, info, **input):
        submitted_by = info.context.user
        # How I manage authentication
        if not group_required(submitted_by, "send_and_receive_texts"):
            custom_response = "You do not have the correct permissions to do this action"
            return RelayCreateConversation(conversation=custom_response)
        # mutation code here
```

And then I have a helper function which I import which is dead simple:

```
def group_required(user, *group_names):
    if bool(user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names)) | user.is_superuser:
        return True
    return False
```

**Limitations:** I currently haven't tried to manage queries with this yet, just functions. If someone gets to that before I do, please comment or update my response.